# Как сделать чтобы выводилось когда два или более совпадений (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

> У меня есть код который смотрит страницу и при нахождении условий присылает сигнал. А именно когда находит на странице red2 или red3 то присылает сигнал. А мне надо его поправить чтобы он присылал сигнал когда есть два или больше двух совпадений. Пример: (red2 red2) или (red3 red3) или (red2 red3 red3) и так далее....

```
td1 = tr.find_all('td')[3].get('class')
td2 = tr.find_all('td')[6].get('class')
checker = 'None'
if td1 == ['red3'] or td1 == ['red2'] or td2 == ['red3'] or td2 == ['red2']:
    checker = 'совпадение'

if checker == 'совпадение':
```

Comment: Посчитайте количество совпадений, если их два или больше - посылайте сигнал

Comment: @user7860670 А каким образом??? Объясните пожалуйста. Что вставить в мой код?

Comment: @user7860670 А каким образом??? Объясните пожалуйста. Что вставить в мой код?